# Why ReSharper doesn't display the shortcut for "Complete Statement"

Tags: resharper

As show http://i52.tinypic.com/97ljwz.png

ReSharper 5.0 doesn't display the shortcut **Ctrl+Shift Enter** for the "Complete Statement" although this shortcut does work in VS2010.

Is there a way that I can let ReSharper display this shortcut on the menu?

// update //

In my VS2010 SP1,

**Edit.LineOpenBelow (Ctrl+Shift+Enter (Text Editor))**

Comment: Override that existing shortcut, you are not using it anyway as you are telling me it already does the R# command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is missing (also for me in R#6 EAP) however you can make it appear by assigning a keyboard shortcut to it (use the same shortcut if you like)

Go Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

search for 'CompleteStatement' and assign like the screenshot below.
[image]

Now the shortcut should appear, as below.

[image]

Comment: Edit.LineOpenBelow (Ctrl+Shift+Enter (Text Editor)) is my current settings

Comment: @q0987 Override that existing shortcut, you are not using it anyway as you are telling me it already does the R# command.

Comment: and dont forget to press 'Assign' when you do.